# Lua Registry in required modules

Tags: lua, lua-api

Are keys set in the registry of a temporary state that's accessed in a module `int luaopen_foo(lua_State*)` adopted in the registry of the calling state?

For example, let's say we have this module:

```
int luaopen_foo(lua_State* state) {
    lua_pushstring("foo");
    lua_pushnumber(10);
    lua_settable(state, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
}
```

And this module is required by lua code:

```
require "foo"
```

Is the key `foo` in the registry from the state `state` adopted into the registry from the calling state?

Comment: The `state` argument passed to that function isn't a "temporary state" it is the lua state that is calling that function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, write this in lua file

`foo = require "foo"`

Comment: Oh of course, that's what I'd normally do. It was just not necessary in my example since nothing is pushed on the stack. (Your answer should be a comment, by the way.)